# How to check if exception is reportable or not in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I have only API laravel project. If I turn the debug mode off in `.env` file by setting `APP_DEBUG=false`, my application throws `Server error` for the errors that shouldn't be shown to user.

But it return json response like this:

```
{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

I want to add code key to it ass well. What I am trying to achieve:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

What I tried so far (`register` method of `Handler`):

```
    $this->renderable(function (Throwable|Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'code' => $e->getCode(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], $e->getCode());
    });
```

But this will return exception message that shouldn't shown to user. I need smth like this:

```
    $this->renderable(function (Throwable|Exception $e) {
        // ReportableException doesn't exist in laravel
        if($e instanceof ReportableException){
            return response()->json([
                'code' => 500,
                'message' => 'Server error'
            ], 500);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'code' => $e->getCode(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], $e->getCode());
    });
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, I don't see anything wrong with the code, but you can always opt to render a **NotFoundHttpException** with the message you desire for the user to see. Example: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is `isHttpException` method that is used to know if exception is reportable or unreportableto user. So that is my solution:

```
   $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) {
        if (!$this->isHttpException($e)){
            return response()->json([
                'code' => 500,
                'message' => "Internal server error"
            ], 500);
        }
        $code = $e->getCode() == 0 ? 500 : $e->getCode();

        return response()->json([
            'code' => $code,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], $code);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You do have access to **HttpResponseException** so you can do something like this:

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException) {
    //Can use this directly for details
    $exception = $exception->getResponse();

    //Or handle the exception manually
    switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
        case 401:
            $response->code = 401;
            $response->message = 'Unauthorized';
            break;
        case 403:
            $response->code = 403;
            $response->message = 'Unauthorized';
            break;
        case 404:
            $response->code = 404;
            $response->message = 'Not Found';
            break;
        case 405:
            $response->code = 405;
            $response->message = 'Unauthorized';
            break;
        case 422:
            $response->code = 422;
            $response->message = '??';
            break;
        default:
            $response->code = 500;
            $response->message = '??';
            break;
    }
}
```

So it will look something like this:

```
if($e instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException){
     return response()->json([
         'code' => $e->getStatusCode(),
         'message' => 'Server error'
     ], $e->getStatusCode());
 }
```

Hopefully this works for you.